# Passing argument from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on MVC application. I am trying to pass argument from view through JQuery to controller using JSON. the return type is working fine but when I pass argument it fails. following is the code

**VIEW**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ClientList").change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetClientData", "Home")',
                type: 'Post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { clientID: $("#CientList").val() },
                contentType: 'application/json; character=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        document.getElementById("ClientName").value = data.clientName
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('invalid ID' + data.success);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetClientData(string clientID)
        {
            Client client = Client.GetClient(Convert.ToInt32(clientID));
            if (client != null)
            {
                return Json(new { success = true, clientName = client.ClientName });
            }
            return Json(new { success = false });

        }
```

If I take out the argument from controller code. It works fine but it fails when method is accepting arguments. Any suggestions?

Comment: You have a typo in your data line.  #CientList should be #ClientList.  Does that typo exist in your actual code?

Comment: No there is no type in the code, I have verified

Comment: I found solution. But I do not know how to paste solution here

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ClientList").change(function () {
            var selectedClientID = { clientID: $("#ClientList").val() };
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetClientData", "Home")',
                type: 'Post',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(selectedClientID),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        document.getElementById("ClientName").value = data.clientName;
                        document.getElementById("ClientAddress").value = data.clientAddress;
                        document.getElementById("ClientContactNumber").value = data.clientContact;
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('invalid ID' + data.success);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

This works perfectly